# Add a break to the placeholder with just css

Tags: html, css, forms

I have this input that I can't change.

```
<input type="text" name="sva-number" value="" placeholder="There is a really long placeholder inside of this input">
```

The form adapts just fine to any screen-size, but the placeholder has to be readable and is not, because the size of the input does not adapt to the text of the placeholder.

[image]

My idea was to change the size of the font:

```
input::placeholder
{
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

but I would have to make it too small, it didn't work. May be there is a way to add a break-line on it with css? Or any other idea?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't found that one. Almost, I will try to set the field as a text area on the plugin to check the difference. Otherwise I will make a tooltip on js.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a new line html entity `&#10`;
Insert it inside the placeholder attribute:

```
<textarea name="foo" placeholder="hello you&#10;Second line&#10;Third line"></textarea>
```

Comment: Probably this would be a good solution. It didn't work, the form is created with a Wordpress plugin, so probably is cleaning the text or it does not work inside of this code to create the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't do it without a little bit of JS for an input field,
why not to increase the width of the input field to about 150-200px, it will still work on every most used device and be visible.

```css
input {
    width: 200px;
}

input::placeholder {
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="sva-number"
            value=""
            placeholder="There is a really long placeholder &#10 inside of this input"
        />

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I could add some javascript code, I didn't realized that. The input is already 240px + styles (like padding) the font size 8px is not small enough and there would be super tiny for the mobile screen, that's why I need an alternative. I will right some tooltip in js on focus.

Comment: When I copied your code, and set the input width to 200px, the whole placeholder fits in the input field, and there is even more space to make the font a little bit bigger, are you sure that you have declared the width to 240px?

Comment: No, I haven't declared on that size, that the size it get's when I see the page with an Iphone 5 screen size and it would be another size with another device. The code is just an example, the thing is that I have an input where the placeholder does not fit. And to make the font-size small was my first approach but it gets too small to read it comfortable on mobile, so I wont do that.

Comment: Yeah ok, I understand now. The best solution I think, as mentioned, is JS.